# How can I fix jagged curved with Photoshop's Gradient Overlay?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, layer-style

I am trying to create an image and added a Gradient Overlay style as seen below.

[image]

I ended up with the following image (A part of image).

[image]

Looking at the area circled in black, you can see a jagged curve. This is not as designed and occurs when I add the Gradient Overlay layer style.

[image]

**Can someone suggest how to get a smooth curve, without this jagged structure, when using the Gradient Overlay layer style?**

Edit:

Image without gradient fill (without zooming)

[image] 
 [image]

See the above two images. The left one is the actual one and the black line in the right image is the area where you need to look into. You can see zigzagged border over there.

Comment: Seems to me the shape itself is jagged. You'd need to create a mask with the pen tool to smooth that out.

Comment: I used tranform (ctrl + T) in windows and used warp option to design it. I intentionally didnt change it to jagged one.
Could you suggest if that operation would make the image jagged?

Comment: post a picture with solid color effect instead of gradient. And what is white shape over gradient?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Edited the question by Adding image removing gradient fill. Have a look at it

Comment: What is the resolution of the file (ppi)? Zoomed in to 300% on a low resolution file, you are going to see pixels in most cases.

Comment: I have edited the question without zooming the image. Even in this case i am seeing some zigzagged curve.Can you suggest me.

Comment: "Image without gradient fill " but there still is organe-pink gradient..which part are you talking about again...confused now.

Comment: edited the question. Can you check it again please.

Comment: zizzag is happening because you are too zoomed in or the shape is isn't vector but pixels and was transformed that way. Simply use pen tool trace over it make a shape that looks like it and then give that gradient.

Comment: this happens when you transform pixel based shape/image too much. Solution is what i told you. Use vector shape.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that's what you want but if you don't want to use Illustrator, you can try this:

1) Use the circle selection tool, and draw a big oval that has a similar curve to your design's curve. You'll probably need a few try.

2) Go in the menu "select", and then choose "inverse".

3) The next step will be to delete what's outside of that curve to smooth it, so if necessary, deselect what you don't want to see deleted on that layer (use the rectangle or any selection tool and press ALT to deselect the parts you don't want to see selected)

[image: How to correct a curve in Photoshop]

4) Delete OR use a layer mask.

You can do the same with your other curves if you need to. It will make a perfect curve and clear slice.

[image: How to correct a curve using the selection tool in Photoshop]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is down to the image being pixel based. A Vector shapes would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

As previously noted using vector shapes is a work around for this, however if you're bound to raster graphics, apply the gradient as a mask layer to the object, it will retain the previously smooth edge.